# Why does EF 6.1.3 persist in generating the string value as Unicode?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following classes defined:

```
private class Entity
{
    public int? Number { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`Entity` is not a Model class which exists in the database, rather I want to map output to it instead of an anonymous type.

```
public static class EntityTypeName
{
    public const string Dealer = "DEALER";
}
```

Later, in my code I have the following Entity Framework query:

```
IRepository<DealerMostCurrent> repoDealer = new Repository<DealerMostCurrent>(context);
IRepository<DealerContact> repoDealerContact = new Repository<DealerContact>(context);
IQueryable<Entity> dealerEntity;

dealerEntity = from dealerRow in repoDealer.GetAsQueryable(dealerWhere).AsNoTracking()
               join dealerContactRow in repoDealerContact.GetAsQueryable(dealerContactWhere).AsNoTracking() on dealerRow.Dealer_Number equals dealerContactRow.Dealer_Number
    group dealerRow by new 
    {
        dealerRow.Dealer_Number,
        dealerRow.Dealer_Id,
        dealerRow.Dealer_Name
    } into groupedDealers
    select new Entity()
    {
        Number = groupedDealers.Key.Dealer_Number,
        Type = EntityItem.EntityTypeName.Dealer,
        Id = groupedDealers.Key.Dealer_Id,
        Name = groupedDealers.Key.Dealer_Name
    };
```

If I look at the generated SQL for the EF call, I see that Entity Framework is casting my `EntityItem.EntityTypeName.Dealer` constant which is defined as a `String` to `N'DEALER' AS [C1]`,

```
SELECT 
[Distinct1].[Dealer_Id] AS [Dealer_Id], 
[Distinct1].[Dealer_Number] AS [Dealer_Number], 
N'DEALER' AS [C1], 
[Distinct1].[Dealer_Name] AS [Dealer_Name]
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
    [Extent1].[Dealer_Id] AS [Dealer_Id], 
    [Extent1].[Dealer_Number] AS [Dealer_Number], 
    [Extent1].[Dealer_Name] AS [Dealer_Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[DealerMostCurrent] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DealerContact] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Dealer_Number] = [Extent2].[Dealer_Number]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Dealer_Id] > 0) AND ([Extent2].[Contact_Id] IN (1473,1475,1477,1481))
)  AS [Distinct1]
```

It seems that EntityFramework is ignoring my `[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")` on my output mapping class.  If I explicitly tell Entity Framework that `Type = System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode(EntityItem.EntityTypeName.Dealer)` then all is fine and the string is not typecast to Unicode.  Am I missing something here?

Also, In my `OnModelCreating` I thought that doing the following would explicitly force EntityFramework to treat all string types as not Unicode.

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(p => p.IsUnicode(false));
```

What piece of the puzzle am I missing or misunderstanding. **How do I force EntityFramework to treat all .NET `String` types as not Unicode**? I would rather not have to go through all my code and add `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.AsNonUnicode` in all the places where I am setting a constant string value.

Comment: What are you asking? `N'Dealer'` just a hard-coded string that your own code adds in the last select, ie `Type = EntityItem.EntityTypeName.Dealer`. If there are any issues, it's using `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR` and using joins instead of specifying relations between the entities

Comment: EF doesn't convert anything in this case. Strings in .NET *are* Unicode.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand that String are Unicode in .NET, however on the output `Entity` class I have specified an attribute of `[Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]` and additionally specified a length.  I would expect Entity frame to generate the value in the select as `'DEALER' AS [C1]` and not `N'DEALER' AS [C1]` in the select.

Comment: Your query returns just a hard-coded *Unicode* value. Why should it be `'DEALER'` instead of `N'DEALER'` ? You specified a *column* mapping but there is *no* column involved here, just a hard-coded string. That's why I have to ask *again*. Are you just asking or do you have an actual problem?

Comment: Actually both `'DEALER'` and `N'DEALER'` are wrong. It would be better that the constant value is not even send to the DB, and used locally to generate the result object, since that piece of data doesn't intereacts at all with the rest of the DB.

Comment: me 2 I do not see any problem! N'DEALER' AS [C1], come from the linq translation which is used in your select new Entity() why you think it should be sent to the database and it should be not  N'Dealer'? maybe you can update the question and post the related entites

Comment: @BassamAlugili @Alejandro The short of it is that the `Entity` results are returned as an `IQueryable`.  That `IQueryable` is later used to join to another `IQueryable` on the value of the `[C1]` column, which causes an unnecessary cast from nvarchar to varchar.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  to be clear:  How do I force Entity Framework to treat all .NET string types as non unicode.

Comment: Where did the cast appear and why is it a concern? Because if it is `cast(N'DEALER' as varchar(10)` it's essentially a no-op. The problem here is the attempt to shoehorn a certain, probably unnecessary behaviour. Besides, using joins in EF is a very strong smell, just as it is with any other ORM.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the cast causes SQL Server to not use an index.

Comment: Simplify your code then. EF is an Object-relational-Mapping tool, not an alternative to SQL.  If you have to use fake entity classes, the code is far too complex already. Use views to simply the joins or use proper relations.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the input, but there without going into detail there is a reason the code is structured the way it is.  The question is specifically asking if there is some way to force EF to treat all .NET strings as non unicode.